# Identify if a particular DOM object is actually a slider object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, slider

I am using a [JQuery slider](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/index.html) and it works great, however for a particular function I need to find out of a particular object is a slider, if so I would like to perform some specific code.

The slider in my HTML form is named mySlider. I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
if($("#mySlider").type() === "slider") {
    alert("Yes, a slider it is");
}
else {
    alert("No, this is not a slider :(");
}
```

I have tested .type(), .is("slider"), .is("rangeslider"), .is("input:slider"), .role() but none of them seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution here if the plugin doesn't expose a method for this (which is sadly rare) is to look for something that the plugin adds to the element. In this case, it looks a lot like it adds a `ui-slider-input` class. So:

```
if ($("#mySlider").hasClass("ui-slider-input")) {
    // Yes
} else {
    // No
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Testing if all selected elements are jQuery Mobile sliders

As [T.J. Crowder has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814908/3773011), the best solution is for the API to explicitly expose a method to make this determination. Unfortunately,  jQuery Mobile does not expose a specific detection method for sliders. However, they do expose a method that can be used for that purpose.

While it is not explicitly intended as such, the [`option()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#method-option) method can be used to determine if an element is a jQuery Mobile slider. If the element is a jQuery Mobile slider, it returns an object. If it is not a jQuery Mobile slider, or is not *yet* a jQuery Mobile slider, it throws an error.

In the code below, after the function for testing the `selector`, `isMobileSlider()`, is declared, a considerable amount of console output is generated to verify test cases both prior to the `document` being ready and upon `$(document).ready()`.

```js
function isMobileSlider(selector){
    try{
        var toReturn=false;
        $(selector).each(function(){ //may have a collection
            if($(this).is('input')){
                //slider('option') can return an object for a random selector, so
                //  we must test that this is an <input>.
                $(this).slider('option');  //Does not throw if implicitly iterated.
                toReturn=true;
            }else{
                toReturn=false; //Instead, could just throw here, as we already catch
                return false; //Exit each()
            }
        });
        return toReturn;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
function logResults(when){
    console.log('#mySlider is a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#mySlider'));                      //true after ready
    console.log('#slider-2 is a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#slider-2'));                      //true after ready
    console.log('#slider-3 is a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#slider-3'));                      //false
    console.log('All <input> are jQuery Mobile sliders' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('input'));                          //false
    console.log('All jQuery Mobile sliders' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#mySlider,#slider-2'));            //true after ready
}
logResults(' (immediate)');
$( document ).ready(function(){
    logResults(' (on ready)');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<label for="mySlider">jQuery Mobile slider (mySlider):</label>
<input type="range" name="mySlider" id="mySlider" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
<label for="slider-2">jQuery Mobile slider (slider-2):</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
<label for="slider-3">Non-jQuery Mobile slider (slider-3):</label>
<input data-role="none" type="range" name="slider-3" id="slider-3" value="60"
       min="0" max="100" />
<!--Extra vertical space so the snippet can be scrolled to see the second slider-->
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

### Testing if all selected elements are, or will be, jQuery Mobile sliders

The method above, `isMobileSlider()`, returns false if the test is performed prior to jQuery Mobile running (i.e. initializing the slider). There are times when we might want to test to see if the `<input>` will become a jQuery Mobile slider when jQuery Mobile executes.  To do so, we can test for the conditions which are [used by the API](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/index.html) ([docs for current 1.4 version](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/)) to determine if the `<input>` will be a jQuery Mobile slider. Specifically, this is `<input type="range">` and the `<input>` does not have the attribute `data-role="none"`. Note: the documentation also states that a `<label>` with a `for` attribute matching the `id` of the `<input>` is required. But, testing indicated jQuery Mobile does not actually enforce that requirement (i.e. the `<input>` will be a jQuery Mobile slider even without such a `<label>`).

In this case, this test, `willBeMobileSlider()` in the code below, can not be used to test the `<input>` after jQuery Mobile runs because the relevant attribute, `type`, of the `<input>` is changed to `type="number"`. As a result of this, to cover both testing prior to jQuery Mobile running and after jQuery Mobile has run we must use two different tests. The two tests can, of course, be combined to determine if the element, or selector, is or will be a jQuery Mobile slider. In the code below, this is done in `isWillBeMobileSlider()`.

The following code implements tests which will detect that all elements represented by the `selector` either are a jQuery Mobile slider, or will become jQuery Mobile sliders once jQuery Mobile runs. The tests are implemented as separate functions in case it is desired to test for only is, or only will be. As with the code above, after the functions for testing the `selector` are defined, a considerable amount of console output is generated to verify test cases both prior to the `document` being ready and upon `$(document).ready()`.

```js
function willBeMobileSlider(selector){
  //Relies on documented criteria for being a jQuery Mobile slider.
  //Only valid _before_ jQuery Mobile has run.
  //Prior to jQuery Mobile running, it will indicate that it will be a jQuery Mobile
  //  slider once that is run.
  if($(selector).is('input[type="range"][data-role="none"]')){
     return false;
  }
  return $(selector).is('input[type="range"]');
}

function isMobileSlider(selector){
    try{
        var toReturn=false;
        $(selector).each(function(){ //may have a collection
            if($(this).is('input')){
                //slider('option') can return an object for a random selector, so
                //  we must test that this is an <input>.
                $(this).slider('option');  //Does not throw if implicitly iterated.
                toReturn=true;
            }else{
                toReturn=false; //Instead, could just throw here, as we already catch
                return false; //Exit each()
            }
        });
        return toReturn;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}

function isWillBeMobileSlider(selector){
  return (willBeMobileSlider(selector) || isMobileSlider(selector));
}

function logResults(when){
    console.log('#mySlider will be a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + willBeMobileSlider('#mySlider'));                //true before ready
    console.log('#slider-2 will be a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + willBeMobileSlider('#slider-2'));                //true before ready
    console.log('#slider-3 will be a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + willBeMobileSlider('#slider-3'));                //false
    console.log('All <input> will be jQuery Mobile sliders' + when + ':' 
                + willBeMobileSlider('input'));                    //false
    console.log('All jQuery Mobile sliders will be' + when + ':' 
                + willBeMobileSlider('#mySlider,#slider-2'));      //true

    console.log('#mySlider is a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#mySlider'));                    //true after ready
    console.log('#slider-2 is a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#slider-2'));                    //true after ready
    console.log('#slider-3 is a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#slider-3'));                    //false
    console.log('All <input> are jQuery Mobile sliders' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('input'));                        //false
    console.log('All jQuery Mobile sliders are' + when + ':' 
                + isMobileSlider('#mySlider,#slider-2'));          //true after ready

    console.log('#mySlider is or will be a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isWillBeMobileSlider('#mySlider'));              //true
    console.log('#slider-2 is or will be a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isWillBeMobileSlider('#slider-2'));              //true
    console.log('#slider-3 is or will be a jQuery Mobile slider' + when + ':' 
                + isWillBeMobileSlider('#slider-3'));              //false
    console.log('All <input> are or will be jQuery Mobile sliders' + when + ':' 
                + isWillBeMobileSlider('input'));                  //false
    console.log('All jQuery Mobile sliders are or will be' + when + ':' 
                + isWillBeMobileSlider('#mySlider,#slider-2'));    //true

}

logResults(' (immediate)');
$( document ).ready(function(){
    logResults(' (on ready)');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<label for="mySlider">jQuery Mobile slider (mySlider):</label>
<input type="range" name="mySlider" id="mySlider" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
<label for="slider-2">jQuery Mobile slider (slider-2):</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
<label for="slider-3">Non-jQuery Mobile slider (slider-3):</label>
<input data-role="none" type="range" name="slider-3" id="slider-3" value="60"
       min="0" max="100" />
<!--Extra vertical space so the snippet can be scrolled to see the second slider-->
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Note: The class that [T.J. Crowder chose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814908/3773011) is a good choice for the current implementation of jQuery Mobile sliders. In addition to various other changes to the DOM, there are several other classes which are added to the `<input>` element. Any of these changes could be used. In this instance, the class `ui-slider-input` appears the most specific. However, it relies on the undocumented internal implementation of jQuery Mobile sliders (i.e. that the class `ui-slider-input` will continue to be applied).

It should be further noted that the `Option()` method throwing an error when the `<input>` is not a jQuery Mobile slider is also not specifically documented.

Which test should be used, testing for the class `ui-slider-input` or the `Option()` method throwing an error, is open for debate. In my opinion, testing for an error being thrown is somewhat better. The mechanism of throwing an error prior to initialization appears to be a choice across the entirety of jQuery Mobile, not just sliders. Whereas, using the class `ui-slider-input` is specific to jQuery Mobile sliders. Thus, changing the error throwing behavior is a larger, more sweeping change than changing the class. Therefore, it will, probably, be less likely for the error behavior to change than for the class name used on the element to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

On similar lines as @T.J. Crowder answer:

```
if(typeof $('#mySlider').slider === "function"){
      //YES
}
```

Comment: No, that will be true on **all** jQuery objects. Otherwise, plugins wouldn't work at all.